# What notice should Bob give when he takes a web app under Apache2, changes UI and the database, then hosts it?

Tags: copyright, apache-2.0, open-source-definition

Question asked [here](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/85734/what-notice-should-bob-give-when-he-takes-a-web-app-under-apache2-changes-ui-an), but without much attention; posting here.

Please write a bit of detail steps on how to follow Apache2 requirements for a new beginner, (whose native language is not English,) Thank you.

Bob found a web app on GitHub, it is with Apache License 2.0 license, and also builds on top of other projects with Apache License 2.0 license. Now, Bob would like to work on the UI and replace the entire database. When Bob hosts it later, what information/ licenses of Apache 2 should he include on that website to meet the Apache License 2.0 requirements? So far, Bob's understanding is:

```
Conditions
License and copyright notice
State changes
```

What are the exact steps Bob needs to do to meet the Apache-2 requirements?

And how to show the Apache2 License and copyright notice on the website (the unchanged web app doesn't have any Apache notice after build)?

Comment: Are you distributing either code or binaries to the users, or are you simply allowing them to access a web site which runs the code? (Note that any JavaScript code is typically distributed to the users)

Comment: Just trying to host it on the internet.  Simply allowing people to access the website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Apache license requirements are on *distribution* of the software to others (Section 4), not on using the software or allowing anyone else to access it. Therefore if all you are doing is hosting the software on your<sup>1</sup> server, you do not need to do anything.

<sup>1. Hosting software on a cloud server over which you have some kind of exclusive usage rights is generally thought not to be distribution - i.e. you can host the software on AWS/Azure/GCP without worrying about it. What you can't do is to give it to a customer for them to host on *their* server.</sup>

Comment: What about the License and copyright notice? (since sometimes we can see some site like "Power by Wordpress"; is this copyright notice?  The untouched/original UI/font end doesn't show any Copyright information.)
After we modify the UI or database,  we don't need to "State changes" ?

Comment: If you have more general questions about licenses and copyright law, you should ask a different question, although please review the questions on both this site and Law SE first.